# Laptop lid must be closed and reopen to light on screen

Tags: windows-10, display, lid

Lenovo Y520-15IKBN (core i5 version without M.2)
Model:      80WK

I'm having this laptop model (running Windows 10 of course), several condition here before proceed:

Pre-story background about problem:

1. while laptop is in running state (screen ON), remain lid open

   a. SHUT DOWN laptop (NOT restart, and lid remain open all the way)
   b. POWER ON laptop (by pressing power button, lid is still open)
   c. ONLY LENOVO logo is shown at very beginning of boot
   d. EVERY THING about WINDOWS SCREEN remain BLACK screen
   e. close lid now (fully close until tight)
   f. open lid 
   g. Screen is shown now (with little blinking like how you update your screen resolution, or when you start off a fullscreen game that run in 1280p but desktop is in 1920p, that kind of little flashing)

However, another situation :

2. Repeat exact steps in STEPS 1 but click RESTART directly this time and I DO NOT NEED to close LID this time, screen just ON normally

I think this should be something because while RESTART, laptop does not fully cut off power supply, so screen can on as normal during RESTART.

First, I do not sure my laptop is it really using magnet as well to detect lid. However I do found a spot left side of my screen where my AAA battery can be suck and stick on screen border, but it's only on lid side, not on main board side (aka. left edge of keyboard), nothing happend around keyboard.

**Side info: Why this happened at first place?**

This happened one day, I went out home and left it running without plug-in power, and let it run on battery until finish and dead (I didn't observe entire process of how it dead). It could be something  power off unexpected or even burnt and cause this whole issue. From that day onward, I thought my screen is dead (still can hear startup sound at that time) until I accidentally close lid and reopen and everything comes back. like baby resurrected.

**So...**
How can I fix it ? and from where I can start looking for if I want to check on my own? but prefer not to disassemble screen lid if possible :( I am not expert anyway. Thanks for reading

UPDATE:
Some people have feedback I need to turn off fast startup (in Control Panel / Power Options) but I don't think that is related because screen is on itself only when RESTART , but fast boot doesn't affect on RESTART

Comment: Everything works fine on restart when fast startup doesn't apply. Screen doesn't work at cold boot when fast startup is relevant. How does that rule out fast startup?

Comment: I suspect this might be due to hardware power management issue, I've had similar problems with peripherals where they fail to recover from S3 sleep state when returning from hybrid sleep.  If the hardware in question isn't enumerated in Device Manager, you can try to narrow it down and modify via `cmd` instead, but before that try making sure all your BIOS, drivers, and firmware are all up-to-date from OEM directly.

Comment: anyway, I did turn off fast startup and it doesn't make any different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just notice it solve after I updated my BIOS provided from Lenovo official website. I discovered this very late because update BIOS in Lenovo offiacial app never success and I not bother it for sometimes. Somehow I managed to "flash BIOS" to force it update. Therefore it finally updated my BIOS.